# Will celeryd restart drop currently running tasks?

Tags: celery, celeryd

If I have two worker processes doing long-time operations. If I use `/etc/init.d/celeryd restart` as in the official document to restart them when they are in the middle of processing tasks, what happens then? Will they wait till they finish the tasks before shutting down? If new tasks keep coming right now, are they lining up in the queue till any worker finishes restarting? Or will celery start a new worker before old ones are shut down and routing new tasks to it so that there won't be any time no workers are available?